# Two identical dates are not the same

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google sheets script editor and it uses JavaScript. My aim is to compare two dates; `date2` is a text string in a cell plus 28 days, and `date1` is today.

This is how I retrieve today's date and convert it to object:

```
function getToday() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
  } 
  if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
  } 
  return dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
}

function stringToDate(str1){ // 
  var dt1   = parseInt(str1.substring(0,2));
  var mon1  = parseInt(str1.substring(3,5));
  var yr1   = parseInt(str1.substring(6,10));
  var date1 = new Date(yr1, mon1-1, dt1);
  return date1;
}

date1 = stringToDate(getToday());
```

This is how I get `date1`, add 28 days and convert it to object:

```
date2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('J4').getValue();
date2 = new Date(date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 28));
date2 = stringToDate(date2);
```

This is how I do the comparison:

```
date1.getTime() === date2.getTime();
```

The above **always** returns false. I do prints at various stages and here are the results:

```
Logger.log(date1)
Tue Mar 29 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016

Logger.log(date2)
Tue Mar 29 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016

Logger.log(date1.getTime());
1.459206E12

Logger.log(date2.getTime());
1.4616252E12

Logger.log(date1.getTime() === date2.getTime());
false
```

As you can see, the [getTime() method returns different values which are the number of milliseconds since epoch](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp). Given that I've parsed both `date1` and `date2` date values in the exact same format, I can only assume the addition of 28 days is the problem.

What else can I try to get this straight?

Comment: `My aim is to compare two dates; date1 is a text string in a cell plus 28 days, and date2 is today.` here I think you inverted date1 and date2 .. That's how it is in the code

Comment: @Puzzle84 that's not his date.. It's the logging date time. It's irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: date1.getDate() == date2.getDate() instead of date1.getTime() date2.getTime()

Comment: @Puzzle84 sadly not, thank you though

Comment: @Reddy, I'm not 100% with you as I disagree that date1 & date2 are inverted

Comment: `date1 is a text string in a cell plus 28 days, ` in your question but in code it is date2.. See this `date2 = new Date(date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 28));`. I was talking abt this

Comment: You're right thanks @Reddy I've updated the question

Comment: @Puzzle84 you're correct, please make an answer and I'll tick. I was tripping over myself as I used different variables to what is in my code.

Comment: Puzzle isn't correct.  `.getDate()` returns the day.  Using that will make May 29 == June 29.

Comment: ^ good point, but doesn't the method take into consideration the month & year as it's working with the object?

Comment: @adampski if you're referring to the `.getDate()` function, then no.  Here, have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/fo0LexL9/

Comment: In this case, Apps Script does not set the date to the `GMT+01:00` time zone in the date string.  It adjusts the time using a time zone offset that the script is set to.  File > Project Properties > Time Zone field.  You can explicitly set the time zone in a date string, but you must use a string format of:  "Month/Day/Year time timezone_Offset" where the timezone_Offset is specified in long format:  [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html)  You must change the date string format.  Using `GMT+01:00` and the format you are using won't work.  It's an Apps Script thing.